# 301 redirect from old site with query strings to new without

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to set up 301 redirects in .htaccess for a new site. The old version of it had pages like `example.com/categorylisting.asp?cat=BK`. The new one will have pages like `www.example.com/books-dvds/`. I have tried many different versions of it, most recently as shown. There will be many different pages that need to be redirected so I need to get the general set up correct at this stage. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

#this works but has no query string
Redirect 301 /testing.html /books-dvds/ 

#this doesn't work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=BK
RewriteRule ^categorylisting\.asp https://www.example.com/books-dvds/? [R=301]


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Try changing the order of your rules. The rule that redirects query string should be at the top of other rules , put it  below `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: I tried this and thank you, I am now getting redirects, but to https://www.example.com/pub/books-dvds/ rather than https://www.example.com/books-dvds/. Is this because of the rule RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]. If I take this out the site breaks.

Comment: I have added [L, to the [R=301] and that seems to have sorted it. Thank you